# Creating HaProxy file for eclipse project and storing in logs

Tags: java, eclipse, haproxy, keep-alive

I need to create a haproxy.config file and when eclipse project runs, store value in log files. Project is on mac.

I have searched on net but not able to find anything on how to run it.